# Vertical spacing using Forest "Folder - Style" too big

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, forest

1. As the real text has quite a few entries I want to decrease the vertical space between the different entries.
2. How to put "Family" into the middle of the page and equally distribute the "Parents" horizontally.
3. Any ideas to make it a little bit more visually pleasing is also greatly appreciated :-)
4. In case someone knows a simple way to generate a similar layout using Tikz I'd be happy to use that instead.

Thanks - Peter
(Pls. apologize that I could not manage to put the minimum working example into the code format)

```
\documentclass[12pt
    ,a4paper
    ,bibliography=totocnumbered
    ,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
 forked edges,
 for tree={
 %draw=black,
 %rounded corners,
 %minimum width=3cm,
 %minimum height=4ex,
 %edge={-Latex},
 },
 where={level()<=0}{%
 anchor=west,%parent anchor=children,
 }{%
  folder,
  grow'=east,
  align=left,
 }
[Family
[Parent A
[Child A
[Grandchild A1]
[Grandchild A2
[GrandgrandChild]
]
[Grandchild A3]
]
] 
[Parent B
 [Child 2
[Grandchild 2a]
[Grandchild 2b]
]
]
[Parent C
[Child 3
[Grandchild 3]
]
]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `l=` and `s sep=` option and manfully shift the family node to the center. This is a relative compact form:

```
\documentclass[12pt
    ,a4paper
    ,bibliography=totocnumbered
    ,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{forest}
 forked edges,
 for tree={
 %draw=black,
 %rounded corners,
 %minimum width=3cm,
 %minimum height=4ex,
 %edge={-Latex},
 },
 where={level()<1}{%
 xshift=35.8pt,
 s sep=-5pt,
 }{%
  folder,
  grow'=east,
  align=left,
  l=20pt,
  s sep=-5pt
 }
[Family
[Parent A
[Child A
[Grandchild A1]
[Grandchild A2
[GrandgrandChild]
]
[Grandchild A3]
]
] 
[Parent B
 [Child 2
[Grandchild 2a]
[Grandchild 2b]
]
]
[Parent C
[Child 3
[Grandchild 3]
]
]
]
\end{forest}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @PeterPauken If this is the answer you were looking for, then please accept it by clicking the check sign on the left.